# Populate collection of objects from one JSON file to the collection of another one with PowerShell

Tags: json, powershell

I have two JSON files and want to transfer collection of objects from one file to another. Suppose, the `from.json` file contains property which represents collection of clients:

```
"Clients": 
[
  {
    "Name": "Name1",
    "Age": "12"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Name2",
    "Age": "14"
  }
]
```

`to.json` file contains an empty collection, `"Objects: []"` ,which must be filled with objects from `from.json`. Each objects in `toJson` variable must contain additional property - `Id`, so eventually, my "to.json" file should look like this:

```
"Objects":
[
  {
    "Id": "{new-id}",
    "Name": "Name1",
    "Age": "12"
  },
  {
    "Id": "{new-id}",
    "Name": "Name1",
    "Age": "12"
  }
]
```

I've converted two files into variables:

```
$fromJson = (Get-Content -Raw -Path {fromPath}) | ConvertFrom-Json
$toJson = (Get-Content -Raw -Path {toPath}) | ConvertFrom-Json
```

I know that objects from `fromJson` to `toJson` can be transferred in the following manner:
`toJson.Objects += fromJson.Clients`, but that's not enough in my case. I think that it could be done by iterating through `fromJson.Clients` array but have no idea how to create an object and add it into `toJson.Objects` collection.

Comment: But where would the`id` come from?

Comment: New-Guid must be created

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a more efficient solution, based on:

- Use of a [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Calculated_Properties) with [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object), which allows you to place the new property *first* in the output objects.
- Instead of building the array *one by one* with `+=` (which is inefficient, because a *new* array must technically be created behind the scenes in every iteration), the solution below lets PowerShell collect the output objects of the `Select-Object` call in an array *automatically* (the `[array]` type constraint is needed to ensure that an array is created even if only *one* object happens to be output.)

```sh
# Sample input.
$fromJson = ConvertFrom-Json '{"Clients":[{"Name":"Name1","Age":"12"},{"Name":"Name2","Age":"14"}]}'
$toJson = ConvertFrom-Json '{ "Objects": [] }'

[array] $toJson.Objects = 
          $fromJson.Clients |
            Select-Object @{ Name='Id'; Expression = { [string] (New-Guid) } }, * 
 
$toJson | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 3 # append | Set-Content as needed.
```

Answer (score 0):

Kind of new to the PowerShell, but after a bit of investigation came up with the following solution:

```
fromJson.Clients | ForEach-Object {
  $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'Id' -Value ([guid]::NewGuid().Guid.ToString())
  $toJson += $_
}
...
$toJson | ConvertTo-Json | Out-File {to.json_path}
```

Frankly, don't know if that is a 'proper' way to do that, but generally it works for that particular case. For now, see no other solution.