# Return an array of unique objects which are specified by properties using PowerShell

Tags: json, powershell, duplicates

I have an object converted from JSON which contains information about 'Trusted clients'. There are two properties one of which identifies the uniqueness of a client: `Name` **AND** `Thumbprint`, so if there are elements, either contain the same `Name` or `Thumbprint`, they must be omitted.

Also, I'd like to point that output array should contain additional property - `Id` which could be generated with - `New-Guid`. That particular case was discussed here: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70473077/populate-collection-of-objects-from-one-json-file-to-the-collection-of-another-o).

```
{
  "TrustedClients": [
        {
            "Name": "Client1",
            "Thumbprint": "5ed7eb688e404bd787585637975ddb01",
            "CallbackThumbprint": "b7f610106fa24afe9460ab8e4f2db1fc"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Client2",
            "Thumbprint": "5ed7eb688e404bd787585637975ddb01",
            "CallbackThumbprint": "b7f610106fa24afe9460ab8e4f2db1fc"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Client3",
            "Thumbprint": "1700a8497495d6053be04b690b98479fd62e6cc9",
            "CallbackThumbprint": "b7f610106fa24afe9460ab8e4f2db1fc"
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there an efficient way to get an array of unique objects specified by `Name` **AND** `Thumbprint` properties? So in that case the output array should contain only one object with name `Client3` since there are two elements with the same `Thumbprint` value:

```
{
  "TrustedClients": [
        {
            "Id": "{(New-Guid).ToString()}"
            "Name": "Client3",
            "Thumbprint": "1700a8497495d6053be04b690b98479fd62e6cc9",
            "CallbackThumbprint": "b7f610106fa24afe9460ab8e4f2db1fc"
        }
    ]
}
```

I was tweaking with *grouping* at first, but it conflicts with the basic idea - uniqueness by `Name` **AND** `Thumbprint`. It's became obvious that *grouping* elements by `Name` **AND** `Thumbprint` potentially could return array with different `Name` values, but the same `Thumbprint` and vice versa.

Comment: "It's became obvious that grouping elements by Name AND Thumbprint potentially could return array with different Name values, but the same Thumbprint and vice versa." - I fail to see how that is at all obvious. Does `$jsonObject.TrustedClients |Group-Object Name,Thumbprint` group objects with different `Name` values together? If so, that's a **bug**.

Comment: May be I miss something, but `$jsonObject.TrustedClients |Group-Object Name,Thumbprint` returns the same array. It's obvious for me that when something are grouped by specifying *keys* the *values* of *keys* itself must be unique. In that particular case, since there are two equal `Thumbprint` with the same `Name`, grouping returns two different objects with different `Name`s but same `Thumbprint`

Comment: Did you forget to post (part of) the input data? There are no two objects with the same `Name` property in the JSON you've posted.

Comment: Sorry, I got what you mean, I believe so. 'It's became obvious that grouping elements by Name AND Thumbprint potentially could return array with different Name values': of course that is not a way to get a unique collection of objects. I've meant that by *grouping* in that case by `Name` and `Thumbprint` is a wrong way to get a desired result. So what I want is to get a unique array of objects where `Name` and `Thumbprint` values don't repeat in any object of an array

Comment: Based on the data you've shown, isn't grouping on `Thumbprint` sufficient then? How do you want to handle the conflicting names? Should the result of merging the first two entries (based on their common thumbprint value `5ed7eb688e404bd787585637975ddb01`) have the `Name` "Client1" or "Client2" (or something else completely)?

Comment: - "isn't grouping on Thumbprint sufficient then? ": grouping by `Thumbprint` is not enough because the idea is to prevent *wrong* user's input;
- "How do you want to handle the conflicting names": I think this is a part of a solution;
- "Should the result of merging the first two entries...?": no, I just want to omit objects with the same `Thumbprint`, if it is possible, of course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I see around it, is to [`Group-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object?view=powershell-7.2) 2 times, on `Name` and on `Thumbprint`, to get those objects that are duplicated, once we have this information we can skip them by filtering the `object[]`.

*I'm using `-NoElement` in this case for efficiency*.

Since I'm a total noob with classes I decided to make one for practicing purposes :)

```sh
class UniqueJSON {
    [object[]]$Items

    UniqueJSON ([pscustomobject[]]$In) {
        $this.Items = $In
        $this.SetGuid()
    }

    [void]SetGuid () {
        $this.Items.Where({ -not $_.ID }).ForEach({
            $_.PSObject.Properties.Add([psnoteproperty]::new(
                    'ID', [guid]::NewGuid().Guid
                )
            )
        })
    }

    [object[]]GetUnique() {
        $thumbNotShow = $this.Items | Group-Object Thumbprint -NoElement |
        Where-Object Count -GT 1
        $nameNotShow = $this.Items | Group-Object Name -NoElement |
        Where-Object Count -GT 1

        return $this.Items.Where({
            $_.Name -notin $nameNotShow.Name -and
            $_.Thumbprint -notin $thumbNotShow.Name
        })
    }
}

# Here you can import your JSON
$json = ..... | ConvertFrom-Json

# Now store the TrustedClients property in a variable
$trusted = $json.TrustedClients

# Create a new instance of the class
$instance = [UniqueJSON]$trusted

# Get the unique results
$instance.GetUnique()
```

- `$instance.GetUnique()` returns:

```
Name    Thumbprint                               CallbackThumbprint               ID
----    ----------                               ------------------               --
Client3 1700a8497495d6053be04b690b98479fd62e6cc9 b7f610106fa24afe9460ab8e4f2db1fc 85af5623-365c-4f8a-9863-be38860406da
```

Comment: Thanks, good trick with `Thumbprint` key. Generally it works for me with minor changes in code.

Comment: @yemo I have updated this answer, the code I provided before would fail on certain occasions